# Where is the real HttpSession class?

Tags: tomcat

I want to know how to implement the HttpSession. When I send a request to the tomcat, it make a HttpSession Instance. I read the `javax.servlet.http.HttpSession`, it's just a interface, I want know the detail about the implementation of the Session.
I want know where can I found the source code from the tomcat src?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/session/StandardSession.html) is Tomcat's

> Standard implementation of the Session interface

If you have downloaded Tomcat's source code navigate to the relevant package to find it.

Or [read it online](https://github.com/apache/tomcat85/blob/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/session/StandardSession.java)